# How can I keep an SSL handshake from timing out?

Tags: python-2.7, ssl, https, proxy

I have a browser that's sending requests through a *very* slow connection to a python web-proxy. The slowness isn't an issue with normal HTTP GET and POST requests, but when I try to open an HTTPS site it's failing. The proxy is getting the CONNECT request from the client and opening the connection with the server, but if the handshake doesn't finish in 30 seconds, the server is ending it.

Is there any way I can modify the proxy to keep the handshake open long enough for the client to finish it? Maybe some sort of SSL handshake keep-alive?

Comment: Modify what proxy? What code? If it's very slow, fix it, or replace it. There are plenty of fast HTTP proxies around.

Comment: I changed my question a little. The proxy is not slow, but the connection between it and the client is. It's not a normal setup and there's nothing I can do to change that. I'm looking for ways, preferably with python, to keep an SSL handshake alive for a period of time.

Comment: Interesting set of constraints! This sounds like it would bring the ability to use SSL to connections with too much latency for "regular" browsing. I'd be very curious about a solution to this.